# How to get response from Guzzle Http in PHP

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, guzzle

I'm building an application in Laravel 5.5 where I'm calling an api request to get response, I've following in my controller:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.conxn.co.in/CoxnsvcA.svc/Login');
dd($response);
```

I'm able to get something like this:

[image: Test]

But while doing `$response->getBody();` I'm unbale to get the response. when I do `dd($response->getBody()` I'm getting:

[image]

In postman it is showing something like this:

[image: test in postman]

Help me out with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `(string) $response->getBody()`? The method will return a stream, which requires special handling depending on what you are trying to do. Maybe you can show a larger part of the code? For example what do you get get instead of the response data when you call `$response->getBody()`?

Comment: @dbrumann It is showing stream sets but I can't find the response where I can retrieve. Give me 2 mins I'll update the question with output value.

Comment: Seems there is an error. In postman result show there is an error with parameter.

Comment: @UlrichDohou yes some update was happening, please check now.

Comment: @dbrumann updated the question please check.

Comment: In your code you did `dd($response)` instead of `dd($response)->getBody()`. Using `getBody()` should return result.

Comment: As I said, the body is a stream. When you do `(string) $response->getBody()` it will make it a regular string. You could also use Guzzle's helper method `$data = $response->json();` to get the data from the response already parsed, when you know it's json

Comment: @dbrumann Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET','http://www.conxn.co.in/CoxnsvcA.svc/Login');

$response_body = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request("GET", "http://www.googleapi.com", ['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]); 

$response_data = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);

return collect($response_data);
```

Comment: Helps somehow with that `json_decode((string)` + `true`. Good one